# Can I "include" a XAML file?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Say I have a very large XAML file called phrase.xaml.  Is it possible for me to remove part of this such as:

```
        <Grid x:Name="tapGrid" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center">
            <Label x:Name="tapScreenLabel" Style="{StaticResource sL}" />
        </Grid>
```

Put that in another file and include it?

Comment: Did you try to do it? What was the result? What code did you use?

Comment: I don't know how to try it.  That's my problem.  I am not even sure it's possible.

Comment: Check out [this](https://blog.falafel.com/creating-reusable-xaml-user-controls-xamarin-forms/) link for an example and come back with specific issues you have following it.